# Display different header images based on current page

Tags: images, templates, headers, custom-header, header-image

I want to display, based on the current page another header image.

Short example:

- Home -> Image A
- PageId 1,2,3,4 -> Image B (2,3,4 are childs of page
  1)
- PageId 5, 6 -> Image C
- ...

I tried to edit the header.php of my theme, because there is the coding block which displays the header image:

```
<?php
                    // The header image
                    // Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
                    if ( is_singular() && has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
                            ( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array( $header_image_width, $header_image_width ) ) ) &&
                            $image[1] >= $header_image_width ) :
                        // Houston, we have a new header image!
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
                    else :
                        // Compatibility with versions of WordPress prior to 3.4.
                        if ( function_exists( 'get_custom_header' ) ) {
                            $header_image_width  = get_custom_header()->width;
                            $header_image_height = get_custom_header()->height;
                        } else {
                            $header_image_width  = HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH;
                            $header_image_height = HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
                        }
                        // echo "here";
                        ?>

                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo $header_image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $header_image_height; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php endif; // end check for featured image or standard header ?>
```

So I try to hook in with following elseif:
*(I removed the `<?php ?>` for easier reading)*

```
if(is_home()){
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo $header_image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $header_image_height; ?>" alt="" />
}else if(is_page(1){
<img src="http://.../ImageB.png" width="<?php echo $header_image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $header_image_height; ?>" alt="" />
}else{
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo $header_image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $header_image_height; ?>" alt="" />
}
```

But that didn't work, instead no header image was shown.

How can I achieve this?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `else if` there is missing a closing bracket: `} elseif ( is_page(1) ) {`.

Since all you alter is the file name, it's sufficient to use the following code:

```
if ( is_home() ) $my_header_image = get_header_image();
elseif ( is_page(1) ) $my_header_image = "http://.../ImageB.png";
elseif ( is_... ) $my_header_image = ...;
else...
?>
<img src="<?php echo $my_header_image; ?>" width="<?php echo $header_image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $header_image_height; ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: So, have you been able to achieve want you asked for?

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didin't work. I'm using the theme twenty eleven as base.

Comment: Unfortunately, I first forgot an `echo` inside the image tag (which I edited/corrected 20 hours ago). Did you see that and included it into your code, or have you tried it earlier (and thus without the missing `echo`)?

Comment: Ohh, but I overlooked that too. But now it works. ;-)